# How to move center <li> in bxSlider if I click any slider <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have created a slider and I'm using **[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)**  in my projects .

Now my requirement is this:

If i click any `li` in than this `li` shift to center in slider with animate .

Can you help me? I've tried searching Google but couldn't found any solution .

My code is this

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainDiv">

<ul class="masterSlider">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></a></li>

            </ul>

</div>
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.masterSlider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        captions: false,
        pager: false,
        minSlides: 5,
        maxSlides: 5,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: 100,
        slideMargin: 10
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ktkmfdL/1/)**

Comment: Really good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit of a challenge with this bxSlider plugin in that how it decides to move doesn't make a lot of sense in relation to slide numbers.

You can see your [modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ktkmfdL/2/)

Now, on the [options page](http://bxslider.com/options) it gives us `getSlideCount()` and `goToSlide()`.  With that in mind, the question is how to determine the current slide being clicked on.  To achieve that I added a `data-slide` attribute to all of the `li` elements.  Then tossed a listener on the `masterSlider` element for `li`'s.  When an `li` is clicked, I then get the slide number from the `data-slide` attribute and adjust it to subtract 2 (that causes centering) and protect against negative numbers.  Finally, I call `goToSlide` with this value.

The plugin, though, will detect if a cloned copy is to the right of the visible screen (in some cases) and scroll you to the right rather rapidly, giving a not-so-pleasant experience, but it does end on the correct slide in the center.

Modified HTML:

```
<ul class="masterSlider">
    <li data-slide="0"><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li data-slide="1"><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li data-slide="2"><a href="#"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Modified JS:

```
var masterSlider;
$(document).ready(function(){
    masterSlider = $('.masterSlider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        captions: false,
        pager: false,
        minSlides: 5,
        maxSlides: 5,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: 100,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
    $('.masterSlider').on('click', 'li', gotoSlide);
});
function gotoSlide() {
    var idx = (parseInt($(this).data('slide')) + masterSlider.getSlideCount() - 2) % masterSlider.getSlideCount();
    masterSlider.goToSlide(idx);
}
```

Comment: HI @Jeremy Miller can i used to this effiect in my bx slider http://examples.mixeek.com/gallery/ if my page started load as like This

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as I don't see that one rotating -- when you click the window popups up.  Would have to see your attempt to make it work. My bedtime now, though, so I'll have to check tomorrow once you've got something if you have another question.

Comment: Thank you, its working. What I had to do to make it work like I needed it was to subtract 3, not 2 so the thumb was in the middle. +1

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if i understood correctly, you want  to  move with animation the  image `li`  when it is clicked to the center of the slider.  i've never really worked with bxSlider but anyway if it is using jquery you  can just animate the image clicked to the center of the container.

```
$('.masterSlider').children().click(function(){
             var witdh =   $('.masterSlider').width;
             var imgwdth = $(this).width;
         $(this).animate({
               marginLeft: (width/2)-(imgwdth/2);
         }, 400);
});
```

let me know if this was what you were looking for, it may not work perfect 'cause  I didn't test it.